# Android, call interface method from anonymous thread in another class

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, dialog

My Activity implements an interface IProcess.

I have a class called Scaler with a static method inside called doProcess().

doProcess contains an anonymous thread which calls an processing method that updates its progress as it runs.

When the process is done I want to call the interface method on My activity which implements IProcess to show a dialog, however, I am getting an exception at the point the dialog should show, saying:

```
04-06 08:43:54.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6832): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

What am I doing wrong, wnad what would be the alternative way (if this is wrong) to display the dialog back in my main activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to notify the UI thread from another thread you should use [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I tried putting my interface call in a runnable and posting it with a handler but the runnable has no reference to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a "one-shot" background taks, you can use an `AsyncTask` where you do the processin in `doInBackground()` and from there call `publishProgress()`. The system then calls `onProgressUpdate()` from where you may manipulate UI elements.

You can find an example here: https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TweetListActivity.java#L328

PublishProgess is e.g. called on lines 391 and 403 and onProgressUpdate start on line 451.

See also the [documentation for AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: This is a one time process, it only needs to be done once ... ever. Do you have an example of how I might use this?

Comment: Thank you, it is an interesting read, I chose not to use this method here though since I was having problems accessing the applications assets from the ASyncTask.